# Check progress of cURL

Tags: php, curl

Is there some way to check the status of a curl command?  Say, I have a call to curl from php, using exec to initiate it.  Is there a way I can check the progress of it while it's running?  Or do I have to wait for it to finish?

exec("curl $url -k > /dev/null 2>&1 &");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a progress function:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'my_progress_handler');
```

> The name of a callback function where
> the callback function takes three
> parameters. The first is the cURL
> resource, the second is a
> file-descriptor resource, and the
> third is length. Return the string
> containing the data.

For further information, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Attention: [This comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#91952) disputes PHP's own function signature.

You **cannot** use [`exec()`](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), because it is a blocking function. It will wait, until the program at hand has terminated.
Edit: Oh, I see that you have used the ampersand, nevermind

What you *could* use is [`popen()`](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php), but unless curl has a nice way of outputting the progress, this isn't going to be pretty.

I would suggest passing `-#` as parameter to `curl`, that way you can grab the progress nicely off the output stream.

Comment: But does that work for curl commands called asynchronously through exec?

Comment: Exec will not block of the command is run as a job with &. However, you wont get any output.

Comment: No, that will work via `curl_init()` and `curl_exec()`. @datasage: yes, I just noticed and corrected that in my last edit.  But still, `popen()` or `proc_open()` is going to be prettier, because you get the outstream stream handles directly.

Comment: Hmm, never looked at popen or proc_open, but checking into it now.  Have you had experience with running commands asynchronously through them successfully?

Comment: No, I have never needed to do so myself, I just know that it is there :)

Comment: CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION is not supported in php versions lower than 5.3.0
so don't waste your time if you are trying to make CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION work in lower versions...